# syntax error, unexpected '}' - weird

Tags: php

I'm using the code down below to delete old files, but it keeps saying: `syntax error, unexpected '}'`, but I can't spot where, please help me to fix it..

```
function destroy($dir) {
$mydir = opendir($dir);
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
        if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
            chdir('.');
            while($dir.$file) {
                if(date("U",filectime($file) >= time() - 3600)
                {
                    unlink($dir.$file)
                }
            }

        }
        else
            unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
    }
}
closedir($dir);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function destroy($dir) {
$mydir = opendir($dir);
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
        if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
            chdir('.');
            while($dir.$file) {
                if(date("U",filectime($file) >= time() - 3600)) // missing )
                {
                    unlink($dir.$file); // missing ;
                }
            }

        }
        else
            unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
    }
}
closedir($dir);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! - im going accept this but it says i have to wait 13 min

Comment: weird now it says : syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: check my edit, you missed a bracket too.

Comment: I see, but it says now : arning: readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory Warning: closedir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory

Comment: you cant read `$dir`, you need to `readdir($mydir);`

Comment: Chris just in case... the script delete the file when i run it anyway, it dont wait 3600 seconds, what wrong??

Comment: maybe try a sleep function. in any case waiting 60 minutes for a file to delete isnt really going to work in php